# Convergence a.e. of the $L^{\infty}$-norm for a vector function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove (or disprove with a counterexample) the following statement:  if $g_n(x) = (f_{1n}(x), f_{2n}(x), \ldots, f_{nn}(x))$ is a vector function defined in a measurable set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ such that each component converges to zero a.e. on $U$ (that is, $f_{kn}(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.e. on $U$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$) then $||g_n(x)||_{\infty} := \max_k |f_{kn}(x)| \rightarrow 0$ a.e. on $U$. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean convergence for a fixed $x$???

Comment: This is confusing. Do you ask about a.e. "point" convergence, or about $L^\infty$ convergence?

Comment: In general, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_{k,n} = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{k \in \{1,...,N\}} \alpha_{k,n} = 0$. This has nothing to do with measures, $L^\infty$, etc.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. 

To Peter Franek: 
Yes, some confusion in notation $||.||_\infty$. For a vector $(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $||(a_1,...,a_n)||_\infty := \max_{k=1,...,n}|a_k|$. In the stated assumptions, I'm asking about the convergence of $\max_{k=1,\ldots,n} |f_{kn} (x)| \rightarrow 0$ a.e. on $U$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The maximum is taken over $\{1,...,n\}$ and not over $U$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if for every $k=1,\dots,N$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_{k,n} = 0$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{k \in \{1,\dots,N\}} \alpha_{k,n} = 0$$ This has nothing to do with measures, $L^\infty$, etc. -- [copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854552/convergence-a-e-of-the-l-infty-norm-for-a-vector-function#comment1762832_854552)

As a consequence, the convergence of $\mathbb R^N$-valued functions in $L^\infty$ norm can be treated coordinate-wise. (Same is true for $L^p$ norms, though one has to argue differently then).